# Webix Data Loading from Laravel Link

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, webix

Trying to load data into a webix data table using the following code. Looks like the browser is getting the json data back, but webix isn't doing anything with the data. No Datatable shows up, but I can still see the full json under the Network -> Response tab in Firefox Inspector. Is this a valid way of loading data into webix?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                    dtable = new webix.ui({
                        container:"box",
                        view:"datatable",
                        select:"row",
                        scroll:"xy",
                        leftSplit:3,

                        url: "{{ url('/getContacts') }}",
                        datatype: "json"
                    });
                </script>
```

Specifically, the question is around whether the url would work as the route for 'getContacts' returns a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting with Webix, we determined that yes. Using the `"{{ }}"`does work for the webix, but for my case, the grid was hidden by a css fault collapsing the rows of the grid. Once that was fixed, the datatable showed up with the data without a flaw.